# loopj Async Http Android Charset

Tags: java, android, http, asynchronous, loopj

How is it possible to set a charset to the AsyncHttpClient? I can't recieve "ü" or something like this in a readable way (just receiving question tags).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

After checking with Loopj documentation you can see that the AsyncHttpResponseHandler can change the charset using a method for the character you want to receive you need charset of UTF-8. [Link](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpResponseHandler.html#setCharset(java.lang.String))
And here is an someone on Github with the same issue and its solution.  [Link](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/268)

Comment: But it should be UTF-8 by default and even when I do `setCharset("UTF-8");` it does not work

Comment: Have you tried changing your project's encoding to utf8? if you're using eclipse its under Project > Properties > Text file encoding

Comment: Yes I'm using eclipse but I can't find Text File encodeing in properties Edit: nevermind, I found it - I just need to test Edit2: Still not working :/ I am receiving text from a php file and if I open this file manually in browser it works with the utf-8